# Java Array Initialization at runtime

Tags: java

I am working on Java based COM program, when I send data in this format so it works:

```
serialPort.writeBytes( new byte[] { (byte)3, (byte)0, (byte)0, 
                                    (byte)0, (byte)4, (byte)5} );
```

but when I do following so it does not, where am I doing wrong?

```
byte[] bcode = null;
bcode[0] = (byte)3;
bcode[1] = (byte)0;
bcode[2] = (byte)0;
bcode[3] = (byte)0;
bcode[4] = (byte)4;
bcode[5] = (byte)5;
serialPort.writeBytes(bcode);
```

Comment: You have to initialize your array before assigning values to it.

Comment: you can't dereference `null`. Period.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the second example, you did not create your array, you assigned it `null`.  You can't reference an array element of an array that doesn't exist.  You could do

```
byte[] bcode = new byte[6];
```

That will create your array with space for 6 bytes.  Then assign your values individually.